# LABVIEW: Is there a logic gate or a combination of logic gates that gives the following

Tags: logic, labview

Is there a logic gate or combination of logic gates that gives the following? If not, is there something that gives the following on Labview

Input: 00, 01  , 10 , 11

Output respectively: 0,1,0,0

I think its unlikely because distinguishing a 1 and 0 with a 0 and 1 doesn't seem to be possible at face value except if its a special gate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like what you want is (NOT A) AND (B). If you can't figure out how to do that in LabVIEW then you seriously need to take a step back and start with some basic tutorials, possibly even go to a proper course. You might also want to look at some more general computer science and programming courses.

Comment: I know how to add logic gates; but I don't know the versatility and limitations of the program. In due time, I will take more accurate programming courses. My current course requires me to use labview but they didn't teach me how to use it properly.

Comment: Thanks just what I wanted :)! Just out of curiosity in the future if I want to do the same, is their a mathematical way to find it. (I couldn't help but also notice that its similar to the not of an implies)

Comment: There are various tools you can use for boolean logic, such as truth tables. I would suggest reading up on the topic. Mostly, it's just a matter of laying out the logic correctly.

If you want some actual advice, I would suggest trying to use only AND and OR (you can use the compound node) and only inverting inputs. That generally makes conditions easier to read (clearer than implies, for instance, and if you look at the example, it's literally the (NOT A) AND B I suggested).

Answer (score 2):

You can do a lot with the Compound Arithmetic node.

[image: Compound Arithmetic]